# Passing a const reference of std::pair to a function

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I recently wrote something like the following. However, I'm very confused that it managed to compile. Well now that it did, I have some questions...

```
void tree_walk(const std::pair<tree, node> &tree_root)
{
   tree t = tree_root.first;
   node current = tree_root.second;

   // code which walks the tree, updating current as we go along.
}
```

I'm wondering if calling tree.first copies the tree? What are the semantics of passing a std::pair as a reference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tree_rooting.first` does not copy anything, but

```
tree t = tree_root.first;
```

does. If you do not want to copy the tree, you can do

```
const tree &t = tree_root.first;
```

To answer your second question: You correctly passed the `pair` to the function as a `const` reference. If you want to modify the input, just leave out the `const` in the functions signature to pass a non-`const`reference.

Answer (score 1):

I fail to see what's confusing here.  You passed a pair by const reference, which contained a tree and a node.  You then made local copies of the tree and the node, and then did stuff with them.  The semantics of a `pair` by const reference are exactly the same as any other type by const reference.

Answer (score 0):

In your piece of code, **tree** is copied in:

```
tree t = tree_root.first
```

If you don't want to change the values present in the **pair** you pass it as **const**, if you want to change the values then you do **NOT** pass it as **const**